# How to format gridview columns?

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel, number-formatting

Below is my code:

```
var grid = new GridView();
grid.DataSource = myDataset;

grid.DataBind();
```

I want to format some of the columns of my grid to Currency with thousand separator and with decimal like '$9,999,999.99'.

I am exporting the grid to excel and I want to see the values in currency format.

I am creating gridview during runtime. I have no html code for my gridview.

I am just bounding dataset to gridview and exporting to excel. I won't see gridview in HTML format.

How to do that?

Comment: You have a higher chance of getting an answer if you (a) tag the question properly, i.e. with the right language tag and (b) accept answers to your previous question.

Answer (score 3):

Create a BoundField for the currency column with appropriate `DataFormatString`.

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="currencyColumnName" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
```

Comment: I am creating gridview during run time . I have no html code for my gridview.

I am just bounding dataset to gridview and exporting to excel. I won't see gridview in HTML format.

Comment: @user. automatic binding can only do so much. If you need it formatted, either do that in the datasource and return it as formatted string instead of number or dynamically add columns with DataFormatString as required.

Answer (score 3):

Google brought me here, so I thought I'd share my answer. Here's how I got to format one cell to currency in asp.net.

```
With Me.ratesGridView
        .Rows(i).Cells(4).Text = FormatCurrency(.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text)
End With
```

Enjoy.